# C : non blocking sockets with timeout : how to check if connection request was made?

Tags: c, sockets, timeout, blocking

I would like to have a server that connects to one client at a time, ignoring connection request when connected to a given client.

I would also liked to avoid the server to get locked when listening for the first client, so that the program can be terminated cleanly.

Apparently, sockets can be made non blocking:
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#blocking

I created my socket accordingly (error management code removed for clarity)

```
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in self;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0));
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); // making this socket non blocking
bzero(&self, sizeof(self));
self.sin_family = AF_INET;
self.sin_port = htons(port);
self.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");   // allowing connection from localhost only.                                            
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&self, sizeof(self));
```

From that point, I am not sure how to manage a timeout. The following code does not work, but gives an idea what I would like to achieve.

```
int client_found = 0;
while ( no_stop_signal && client_found==0 ) {
    listen(sockfd,1);
    if ( ** something that tells me nobody was requesting connection ** ) {
       usleep(10);
   } else {
       client_found = 1;
   }
}
```

Any solution I found so far were concerned about situation more complex than mine (i.e. not ignoring clients once one had been found) and seemed unnecessarily complicated.

EDIT (after accepting answer):

Based on the accepted answer, here the code I came with:

```
static inline int wait_for_client_to_connect(int sockfd, int* server_run){                                                                                                                                                                                  
  int client_found = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  int clientfd = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  struct sockaddr_in client_addr;                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  int addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  if ( listen(sockfd,1) != 0 ) return -1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  while ( client_found==0 && *server_run==1 ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);                                                                                                                                                                                       
    if ( clientfd < 0 ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      clientfd = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      if (errno==EAGAIN || errno==EWOULDBLOCK) usleep(10); // nobody connected, wait for request                                                                                                                                                               
      else return -1; // something wrong, send error                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    } else { // client found, configuring socket and exit                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      client_found=1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      int nodelay_flag = 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      setsockopt(clientfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void*) &nodelay_flag, sizeof(int)); // disable nagle algorithm                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  return clientfd;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

This works, but according to comments and answer, this is not the way to go (apparently a clean way would have something to do with signals ...)

Comment: It sounds like you actually *want* blocking IO - but for some reason you want to use a non-blocking socket and add blocking in your own code (badly). What problems have you found with blocking IO?

Comment: Blocking IO doesn't prevent your program from terminating cleanly. The standard way to handle shutdown with blocking IO is to use a signal handler to set a shutdown flag and then check the flag when listen returns -1 with errno set to EINTR.

Comment: I do not quite understand the solution you are suggesting ... In the code above, the loop is exited if "no_stop_signal" is set to false. Would connecting to a client that send some "stop flag" be the solution you propose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `accept()` on the listening (non-blocking) socket.

If no connection was waiting in the backlog then `accept()` would return immediately with `-1` and `errno` would be set to `EGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

From [`man accept`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> **ERRORS**
>
> **EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK**
>
> The  socket  is  marked nonblocking and no connections are present to be accepted.  POSIX.1-2001 allows either error to be returned for this case, and does not require these constants to have the same value, so a portable application should check for both possibilities.

---

However the `while`-loop your are showing would implement busy-waiting, which is quite expensive.

So why not let `accept` do the waiting by simply blocking until an incoming connection is detected.

To interupt the blocking `accept()` just send the process a signal. `accept()` then would return with `-1` and `errno` being set to `EINTR`.

---

> I would like to have a server that connects to one client

By definitions it's always the client which connects to the server.

Comment: You can use `select()` or `epoll()` with a timeout to detect when a client is pending, then call `accept()` only when a client is actually pending.

Comment: @alk I implemented what your suggested (accept() returning errno ...) and it works fine :) Before I accept the answer, may I ask for more details about the alternative you suggest ? i.e. "just send a process signal" ?

Comment: @alk I do not understand: "To interupt the blocking accept() just send the process a signal.".

Comment: @Vince: Make the process handle a certain signal (see `man 7 signal`). If `accept()` blocks, send this signal to the process and `accept()` will return as described in my answer.

Comment: @alk I do not know what "process" you refer to. Is it my c program ? How do you make a c program "handle a signal" ? I do not understand what means "send a signal to the process". Is "sending a signal" done somehow in c code ? Does it mean having a client connecting to the server that sends data that the server interprets as stop signal ?

Comment: @Vince: You might like to read `man 7 signal` on what signals are and for further reference on how to use them. If you then have a specifc question feel free to pose another question. You then can also leave a link to the question as comment to this answer.