# C : non blocking sockets with timeout : how to avoid busy waiting?

Tags: c, sockets, signals, server, nonblocking

The following code allows for a server to wait for a client to connect to a (already binded) socket. 
It terminates either when a client connects to the socket, or when "server_run" takes the value 0: this allows other part of the code to shutdown the server when suitable to do so.

```
static inline int wait_for_client_to_connect(int sockfd, int* server_run){                                                                                                                                                                                  
  int client_found = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  int clientfd = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  struct sockaddr_in client_addr;                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  int addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  if ( listen(sockfd,1) != 0 ) return -1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  while ( client_found==0 && *server_run==1 ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);                                                                                                                                                                                       
    if ( clientfd < 0 ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      clientfd = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      if (errno==EAGAIN || errno==EWOULDBLOCK) usleep(10); // nobody connected, wait for request                                                                                                                                                               
      else return -1; // something wrong, send error                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    } else { // client found, configuring socket and exit                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      client_found=1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      int nodelay_flag = 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      setsockopt(clientfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void*) &nodelay_flag, sizeof(int)); // disable nagle algorithm                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  return clientfd;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

According to answer and comments to another posts ([C : non blocking sockets with timeout : how to check if connection request was made?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764440/c-non-blocking-sockets-with-timeout-how-to-check-if-connection-request-was-m)), this is not the way to go because it involves busy waiting.

E.g. a comment says :

> "The standard way to handle shutdown with blocking IO is to use a
>   signal handler to set a shutdown flag and then check the flag when
>   listen returns -1 with errno set to EINTR"

It is very unclear to me how the code above could be adapted to "use a signal handler" ....

Comment: Is your program multi-threaded? Or is the _other part of the code_ you mention a separate program that shares the `*server_run` memory with the server?

Answer (score 1):

You want to `select()` on the socket, and only do an `accept` if it is ready for reading. `select()` has a timeout, so you can wait either forever, or perhaps better for a second or two in each loop, as `select` will exit immediately if an FD is ready (here 'ready to read' means 'ready to accept').

Comment: Your suggestion with a timeout amounts to _busy waiting_ quite similarly as Vince's version with `usleep()`, apart from the immediate response of `select()`.

Comment: How can `select()` with a 1 second timeout busywait? I suspect you have got the timeout bit wrong.

Comment: Busy waiting: [_a technique in which a process repeatedly checks to see if a condition is true_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). The length of the timeout makes only a quantitative difference; the qualitative characteristic of the version with `select()` is the same as with `usleep()` - the loop is busy after every timeout - and the timeout, which controls the maximum response time to`server_run`, can be chosen equal.

Comment: Indeed. And (by that definition) it isn't busy waiting whilst it's in `select()` which is about 99.999% of the time.

Comment: Neither is it busy waiting in `usleep()`  for the same percentage of the time if the timeout is chosen equal. But it is the whole loop that matters, not only `select()` or `usleep()`, and thus it *amounts to busy waiting*.

Comment: Vince is doing a usleep for 10 microseconds (which can't be interrupt by the FD becoming ready). I'm suggesting selecting with a timeout for a couple of seconds (which will be interrupted by an FD becoming ready). There are more than 5 orders of magnitude of difference between the two. Please also note that I did not suggest that Vince's answer was (or was not) busywaiting. I'm not sure why you think it is only the loop that matters; the thing that matters is whether it is 'busy' or 'spinning', which this isn't (obviously).

Comment: 1. The length of the timeout is irrelevant to the qualitative characteristic of the implementations, it *makes only a quantitative difference*. 2. It is not expedient to compare different timeouts without noting that an orders of magnitude higher timeout results in an orders of magnitude worse response time to a reset of `*server_run`. 3. What you did question is "_How can select() with a 1 second timeout busywait?_" - Since each of the techniques _repeatedly checks to see if a condition is true_ (the `while` condition), they both clearly _amount to busy waiting_.